# Select from 3 tables (one to many, many to one relationship)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables: 
Recipes (1 --- * ) Ingridients ( *---1) Products. I need to obtain Recipes that contains products in a given list or products that are not in list but have a specific flag set. I have a flag in product table (bool). So where clause looks like:

```
WHERE Product.Caption IN ('A', 'B', 'C') OR (Product.Caption NOT IN ('A', 'B', 'C') AND Product.Flag=TRUE)
```

Important is: I do not need recipes that contain products in list and also contain other products (not in list and flag is false).

Bellow is an example database dump for MSSQL:

```
USE [master]
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = N'movedb') ALTER DATABASE [movedb] SET SINGLE_USER With ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = N'movedb') DROP DATABASE [movedb]
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = N'movedb') CREATE DATABASE [movedb]
USE [movedb]

--
-- Table structure for table 'Ingridients'
--

IF object_id(N'Ingridients', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [Ingridients]

CREATE TABLE [Ingridients] (
  [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
  [Quantity] INT DEFAULT 0, 
  [IdProduct] INT DEFAULT 0, 
  [IdRecipe] INT DEFAULT 0, 
  PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Ingridients] ON
GO

--
-- Dumping data for table 'Ingridients'
--

INSERT INTO [Ingridients] ([Id], [Quantity], [IdProduct], [IdRecipe]) VALUES (1, 0, 1, 2)
INSERT INTO [Ingridients] ([Id], [Quantity], [IdProduct], [IdRecipe]) VALUES (2, 0, 3, 2)
INSERT INTO [Ingridients] ([Id], [Quantity], [IdProduct], [IdRecipe]) VALUES (3, 0, 4, 2)
INSERT INTO [Ingridients] ([Id], [Quantity], [IdProduct], [IdRecipe]) VALUES (4, 0, 6, 2)
INSERT INTO [Ingridients] ([Id], [Quantity], [IdProduct], [IdRecipe]) VALUES (5, 0, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO [Ingridients] ([Id], [Quantity], [IdProduct], [IdRecipe]) VALUES (6, 0, 4, 3)
INSERT INTO [Ingridients] ([Id], [Quantity], [IdProduct], [IdRecipe]) VALUES (7, 0, 8, 3)
INSERT INTO [Ingridients] ([Id], [Quantity], [IdProduct], [IdRecipe]) VALUES (8, 0, 1, 4)
INSERT INTO [Ingridients] ([Id], [Quantity], [IdProduct], [IdRecipe]) VALUES (9, 0, 6, 4)
INSERT INTO [Ingridients] ([Id], [Quantity], [IdProduct], [IdRecipe]) VALUES (10, 0, 5, 4)
-- 10 records

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Ingridients] OFF
GO

--
-- Table structure for table 'Products'
--

IF object_id(N'Products', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [Products]

CREATE TABLE [Products] (
  [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
  [Caption] NVARCHAR(255), 
  [EasyToFind] BIT DEFAULT 0, 
  PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Products] ON
GO

--
-- Dumping data for table 'Products'
--

INSERT INTO [Products] ([Id], [Caption], [EasyToFind]) VALUES (1, N'ProductA', 0)
INSERT INTO [Products] ([Id], [Caption], [EasyToFind]) VALUES (2, N'ProductB', 0)
INSERT INTO [Products] ([Id], [Caption], [EasyToFind]) VALUES (3, N'ProductC', 0)
INSERT INTO [Products] ([Id], [Caption], [EasyToFind]) VALUES (4, N'ProductD', -1)
INSERT INTO [Products] ([Id], [Caption], [EasyToFind]) VALUES (5, N'ProductE', 0)
INSERT INTO [Products] ([Id], [Caption], [EasyToFind]) VALUES (6, N'ProductF', -1)
INSERT INTO [Products] ([Id], [Caption], [EasyToFind]) VALUES (7, N'ProductG', 0)
INSERT INTO [Products] ([Id], [Caption], [EasyToFind]) VALUES (8, N'ProductH', 0)
INSERT INTO [Products] ([Id], [Caption], [EasyToFind]) VALUES (9, N'ProductI', 0)
INSERT INTO [Products] ([Id], [Caption], [EasyToFind]) VALUES (10, N'ProductJ', 0)
-- 10 records

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Products] OFF
GO

--
-- Table structure for table 'Recipes'
--

IF object_id(N'Recipes', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [Recipes]

CREATE TABLE [Recipes] (
  [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
  [Caption] NVARCHAR(255), 
  PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Recipes] ON
GO

--
-- Dumping data for table 'Recipes'
--

INSERT INTO [Recipes] ([Id], [Caption]) VALUES (2, N'RecipeA')
INSERT INTO [Recipes] ([Id], [Caption]) VALUES (3, N'RecipeB')
INSERT INTO [Recipes] ([Id], [Caption]) VALUES (4, N'RecipeC')
-- 3 records

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Recipes] OFF
GO
```

Example:
If I search for ProductA and ProductE it should give me only RecipeC

Right now I have something like this for MySQL ( it is not final. I can only operate with Ids, I neet somehow to change it to work only with product captions and adapt for MSSQL)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    recipes AS r
        INNER JOIN
    ingridients i ON i.IdRecipe = r.Id
WHERE
    i.IdProduct IN (1 , 5, 6)
GROUP BY r.Id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT 
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        ingridients AS ing
    WHERE
        ing.IdRecipe = r.Id);
```

Comment: Try and make your title more descriptive. "Complex Request" means nothing. Try and stay away from words like Complex, what might be complex for you could be a piece of cake for another and doesn't help to describe the problem.

Comment: Sure, thanks, will edit right now.

Comment: What is the question? You posted a script to create a database (not needed), a `WHERE` statement that may be OK, but no complete query or what is the problem. As @Fred mentioned, this doesn't complex at all, you just join the three tables.

Comment: Your database dump does not seem to contain Products.Flag.

Comment: EasyToFind  - bool flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following sql fetches the recipes that contains no products other than those in the list or having P.EasyToFind=-1.

```
select *
From Recipes
Where Id not in
 (
 select IdRecipe
 from Ingridients I
 inner join Products P ON I.IdProduct = P.Id
 where P.Caption NOT IN ('ProductA','ProductE')
 and P.EasyToFind=0
 )
```

It works by having an inner query that identifies the unwanted ingredients and fetching the recipes that does not match any of them.

Comment: Just a sec let me test ;)